# JPQL ManyToMany @JoinTable select query?

Tags: ejb, netbeans-7, jpql

I have 2 entities namely Product and Transaction and these 2 entities are link via a Many to Many relationship. I have the below in my transaction entity.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="Transaction_Product")
```

When I run my project, there will be 3 tables tables created in my database and they are Transaction, Product and Transaction_Product respectively. The Transaction_Product is automatically generated when I run my project.

I am able to get items from my transaction table via this query below.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.fulfillStatus = 0");
```

My question is, how do I get items from the Transaction_Product table?

I tried something like the query below and it did not work.

```
 Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT bt FROM Transaction_Product bt WHERE bt.ProductID = 1);
```

Any help please? :)

Comment: you don't need to get data from that table, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi there. That Transaction_Product contains the transaction ID and Product ID as the primary key. For one of the requirement in my project, I need to make sure that a product can only be deleted if there is no transaction made for the product. Hence, this explain the reason that I want to check the Transaction_Product. If there are rows in the Transaction_Product table based on a certain product ID, the user is unable to delete the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking if there are transactions with specifyed product u can use :

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Transaction t join t.products p WHERE p.id = :id");
```

Assuming that `Transaction` class has field :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="Transaction_Product")
private Set<Product> products;
```